# Use of triangle inequality in contraction mapping

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a part of the proof for the contraction mapping theorem on *Mathematical Analysis I* by V.A Zorich:
[image]

[image]

My question is: how did he use the triangle inequality, by looking at other proofs i saw that it's a repeated aplication of the tirangle inequality, but i still can't see it. Could someone please elaborate on that step?

Comment: Note that $$x_m - x_n = x_m - x_{m-1} + x_{m-1} - x_{m-2} + x_{m-2} - x_{m-3} + \dots + x_{n+1}- x_n$$
Apply the triangle inequality, 
$$\begin{align}|x_m - x_n| &= |( x_m - x_{m-1})  +  (x_{m-1} - x_{m-2}) + \dots + (x_{n+1}- x_n)| \\&\leq | |x_{m}- x_{m-1}| + | (x_{m-1} - x_{m-2}) + \dots + (x_{n+1}- x_n)|\\ &\leq |x_{m}- x_{m-1}| + \dots + | x_{n+1}- x_n|\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key step is as follows: \begin{align*} \lvert x_m-x_n\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^{m-n-1} x_{m-k}-x_{m-k-1}\right\rvert \\ &\leq \sum_{k=0}^{m-n-1} \lvert x_{m-k}-x_{m-k-1}\rvert \end{align*}

The inequality here follows from the triangle inequality (i.e. $\left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\rvert\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert a_k\rvert$).

Comment: Why can Xm-xn be expresed as a sum?

Comment: I underdtand the last step

Comment: @MarkA.Ruiz : You have a sequence $x_m, x_{m+1}, x_{m+2}, x_{m+3}, \ldots, x_n.$ $$ x_m - x_n = (x_m-x_{m+1}) + (x_{m+1} - x_{m+2}) + (x_{m+2} - x_{m+3}) + \cdots + (x_{n-1}-x_n). $$ It can be written as a sum because in that sum all terms cancel except the first one and the last one. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
d(A,G) & \le d(A,B) + d(B,G) \\
& \le d(A,B) + \Big(d(B,C) + d(C,G)\Big) \\
& = d(A,B) + d(B,C) + \Big( d(C,G)\Big) \\
& \le d(A,B) + d(B,C) + \Big(d(C,D) + d(D,G) \Big) \\
& = d(A,B) + d(B,C) + d(C,D) + \Big( d(D,G) \Big) \\
& \le d(A,B) + d(B,C) + d(C,D) + \Big( d(D,E) + d(E,G)\Big) \\
& = d(A,B) + d(B,C) + d(C,D) + d(D,E) + \Big( d(E,G) \Big) \\
& \le d(A,B) + d(B,C) + d(C,D) + d(D,E) + \Big( d(E,F) + d(F,G) \Big) \\
& = d(A,B) + d(B,C) + d(C,D) + d(D,E) + d(E,F) + d(F,G).
\end{align}
In particular
$$
|x_1 - x_7| \le |x_1-x_2|+|x_2-x_3|+|x_3-x_4|+|x_4-x_5|+|x_5-x_6|+|x_6-x_7|.
$$